# How exactly does netflix zuul intercepts the requests/responses?

Tags: security, encryption, microservices, netflix-zuul

i understand that in the micro-service architecture we can make our requests/responses go through the zuul api gateway instead of directly hitting other micro-services, but is this some kind of just a redirection of requests to zuul or zuul actually intercepts the http request over the air.

What i mean is for example,
If a have a micro-service A which communicates to Micro-service B through Zuul. And if i have some encryption/decryption filters written in zuul, then is it that the request goes as plain text from micro-service A to zuul and from zuul to micro-service B it goes as encrypted request? if that is the case then how exactly is zuul helping us with security, because the request is still plain text over the http?

Comment: You wouldn't use Zuul for encrypting your request. You'd use TLS/SSL (HTTPS) for that purpose.

Comment: But is it a good practice to completely rely on the security provided by the network, i mean HTTPS would definitely do its job, but i feel we should still not keep the requests as plain text, even if it passes through HTTPS